# Release pipeline for deployment of .sppkg file to Sharepoint 2019 on prem server

Tags: sharepoint-server, azure-devops

We have created a SharePoint 2019 Onprem Server farm.

Is it possible to develop a CD Pipeline to deploy .sppkg file (CI generated file) to SharePoint 2019 server on prem farm using azure devops build and release pipelines

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible to develop a Continuous Deployment pipeline to deploy .sppkg files to a SharePoint 2019 on-premises farm using Azure DevOps Build and Release pipelines.

Reference：
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66563455/automated-way-to-add-deploy-spfx-sppkg-solution-package-file-to-sharepoint-201